# return subquery value into main query

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_ledger 
WHERE to_id='7' 
AND (SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_in 
     FROM item_ledger 
     WHERE from_item_ledger_id='5') < intransit_qty
```

the query works as expected. From that query, I also want to return `qty_in` to the main query. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery is uncorrelated, so you can simply make it a derived table (moving it to the `FORM` clause) or make it a CTE:

```
-- derived table
SELECT il.*, q.qty_in 
FROM item_ledger AS il
  CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_in 
     FROM item_ledger 
     WHERE from_item_ledger_id = '5') AS q
WHERE il.to_id = '7' 
  AND q.qty_in < il.intransit_qty ;

-- common table expression
WITH q AS
    (SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_in 
     FROM item_ledger 
     WHERE from_item_ledger_id = '5')
SELECT il.*, q.qty_in 
FROM item_ledger AS il
  CROSS JOIN q
WHERE il.to_id = '7' 
  AND q.qty_in < il.intransit_qty ;
```

You could also use an inline subquery or a `LATERAL` join (available in 9.3+ versions) but those solutions would be more useful if the subquery were correlated.

Comment: cool, thanks for the help. I was made it like `SELECT (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM item_ledger WHERE from_item_ledger_id='5') AS qty_in, * FROM item_ledger WHERE to_id='7' AND (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM item_ledger WHERE from_item_ledger_id='5') < intransit_qty`..but I think your solution is better than mine...i'll use it. thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, that (inline subquery) would be one more way to do this. I don't like it particularly because the code would have to be duplicated - although Postgres optimizer is good enough to identify it and only run it once.